# Why IP(Domain) address redirect to localhost instead of IP(Domain) in Grails

Tags: grails

Here is my local domain

```
http://10.10.1.101/uxsurvey/profile/dashboard
```

In controller I set a action for userlist

```
redirect(controller: "Profile",action:"userlist" ,params: [profileID: email]);
```

It rediects `http://localhost/uxsurvey/profile/userlist` instead of `http://10.10.1.101/uxsurvey/profile/userlist`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grails [redirect()](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.0.x/ref/Controllers/redirect.html) method will use grails.serverURL property from Config.groovy for domain in target address or localhost if said config property not specified and application not running in a production environment. So you should either set grails.serverURL to "10.10.1.101" in Config.groovy or run your application in production mode.